# iwconfig not found, but wireless tools installed

Tags: debian, wifi

I want to use iwconfig.

The install of wireless tools:

```
tristan@debian:~$ sudo apt install wireless-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wireless-tools is already the newest version.
```

when i try to run iwconfig:

```
tristan@debian:~$ iwconfig
bash: iwconfig: command not found
```

As you can see I am not able to use iwconfig.

Comment: oh, I see. when I run it after `su` it works. it is installed `/sbin/iwconfig`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `iwconfig` as root :

```
 su -c "iwconfig"
```

Or grant administrative privileges for `user` then run:

```
sudo iwconfig
```

For unprivileged user you  can run `iwconfig`  after adding the following line to your `.bashrc` :

```
export PATH="$PATH:/sbin"
```

Update:

On debian Buster `iwconfig` is under `/usr/sbin` , you can add `/usr/sbin` to your PATH.

Add the following lines to your `/etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin"
```

then :

```
source /etc/environment
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to reinstall wireless-tools :

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall wireless-tools
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you. wireless-tools isn't installed on a Parabuntu by default. This is the answer i was looking for - the package that contains iwconfig!

Comment: same for Kali linux when installed on WSL

Answer (score 5):

You need to be `root` to use `iwconfig`!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check where the `iwconfig` has been placed with `dpkg -L wireless-tools`?

I might be installed in `/sbin/` or `/usr/sbin` which might be missing in the `$PATH` of a normal user.